# Не понимаю как сделать(работаю) POST-запросы на axios, да и в принципе, помогите разобраться. Есть задача

Tags: node.js, парсер, https, axios, cheerio

Я начинающий backend разработчик на nodeJS, столкнулся с проблемой и не знаю как её решить, всю документацию облазил и интернет.

Суть в чём, мне нужно, чтобы скачивалась музыка с определённого сайта, но чтобы музыка скачивалась нужно, **чтобы post-запросом в поисковик на сайте вставлялся текст песни (пример: Мираж - Музыка нас связала) и нажималась кнопка поиска (не понимаю как...)**. Без ReactJS

А дальше я библиотекой cheerio скраплю страницу, нахожу url для скачивания песни, используя axios и готово -- это я знаю как реализовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие библиотеки использовать в таких случаях, может и axios так может, но видимо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, чуваки, после долгово поиска я обнаружил библиотеку puppeteer.
И код, который я так долго пытался реализовать прост до невозможности.
Сайт для парсинга https://ru2.hitmo.top/

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () =>{
    const url = 'https://ru2.hitmo.top/'
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url)

    await page.type("#search", "Би 2")
    await page.click(".search-bar__button")
    await page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    });
    await page.screenshot({path: './img.png'})

    await browser.close()
})();
```

Надеюсь этот пост будет полезен тем, кто также как и я затупил в том, что можно решить в считанные строки